# How to create a master page using HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website which I want to have a consistent style (a header and a side menu) in every page.

I want to create something similar to a master page for it. I don't want to use frames.

How could I achieve this using HTML, CSS, JavaScript and jQuery?

Comment: You might use a templating system: http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Why not do it server-side?

Comment: Not possible in pure HTML. You can use `include()` function if using `PHP`

Comment: don't have option to use server side coding. @nnnnnn

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the new frames?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466265/what-are-the-new-frames)

Comment: don't have option to use any server side code. @ArvindBhardwaj

Comment: @Aisha — Run your template language at build time then.

Comment: I wonder why this good and on topic question is closed

Comment: @Richard "too broad" apparently, though the answer was very precise

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can use jQuery Load function to include header or menu html page, for example, to include a common header html file,

```
    <div id="new-header">
        <script>
            $("#new-header").load("header.html");
        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you for your instant reply. I'll try this and get back to you.

Comment: No problem, I had done it...

Comment: What about the HTML tags, head tags, stylesheets etc ??? How can we call all these within a div ???

Comment: you can load a complete html page, ie, style sheet links, html tags to  a DIV using jquery load

Comment: @Delphian — yes, by throwing them away.

Comment: not working in my case. did the same