# what is called portion of website which is same for all pages

Tags: html

I am Zero in developing websites, but i endup a task to build a simple website with 6-10 html pages. The pages have common sections like headers and footers across all these 6-10 pages.

Now the question is how i build these pages? because the content(headers and footers) in 1st page is same as 2nd page etc... Here it creates redundancy. If i change some content in 1st page, and other changes on Page 2 creates redundancy. Is there any concept called master pages or something like that?

What is the best way to deal with it?

```
<html>
</html>
```

Comment: You are getting some interesting answers.

Comment: Guys, why do you down-vote this question? This is perfectly valid. Not all of us are professional and the community should be friendly with beginners as well.

Comment: Because it shows absolutely no research effort at all.

Comment: Why are all the answers getting down voted?

Comment: @DanielKobe, good question.

Comment: @DanielKobe, anyway, I upvoted yours, to neutralize the negative waves.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this without using Javascript or server side templating is with HTML import. I haven't used it though.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

Answer (score 0):

You have an ocean of oportunities:

- you can use some kind of server technology, like PHP or .NET
- you can create separate pages for the common tools and use them inside iframes
- you can load them with javascript

If you want a quick and dirty solution, then you can go for the iframe solution. But I recommend you to use some kind of server-side technology.

Comment: I have two objects, one is having same content(links) in all these pages and another thing is embed certain pages into a frame. For second task, i think your second "iframe" option helps.

Answer (score -1):

Only using pure HTML you cannot have a masterpage concept, that is impossible.

So you can use simple jQuery Load function to include header or menu html page if you dont want to use any other frameworks (AngularJS,etc) or adapt other languages (PHP,ASP.NET,etc), for example, to include a common header html file,

```
<div id="new-header">
    <script>
        $("#new-header").load("header.html");
    </script>
</div>
```

I got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18464385/2148827)

Comment: [This idea is just literally the worst](https://40.media.tumblr.com/bfe0cfe7b477a8054639746a4e0aec78/tumblr_n8dc27uw1L1qf683zo1_500.png).

Comment: HTML itself is a static language. Other frameworks create dynamic HTML (DHTML) such as ASP.NET.

So a pure implementation of a "masterpage" in HTML is not possible.   Either you have to use AngularJS or some other JS framework..  can you answer for this question if you dare with pure html without JS.. @LegoStormtroopr

Comment: @Prasanthchinja you *don't have to* use a framework.

Answer (score -1):

### PHP + AJAX

In PHP you can create your pages like:

```
header.html
home.php, about.php, contact.php
footer.html
```

Inside **`header.html`** goes everything from `<!DOCTYPE html>` etc... including `<body>`

`about.php` example:

```
<?php include "header.html"; ?>
<h1>This is about</h1>
<p>Content here</p>
<?php include "footer.html"; ?>
```

Inside **`footer.html`** you put everything from `scripts` to `</body></html>`

---

After you're done with your pages in PHP, than you can make the whole even more dynamic, calling a page's `#page` element into the main page using AJAX, changing dynamically URL, manipulating the browser's Hystory etc... using **Javascript**.